# Moxa - NPort 5110 as HTTP Server or similar

Tags: http, webserver, serial, device-mapper

I have a NPort 5110 Serial Device Server connecting our Automation Control Box to the LAN so we can communicate with it from a non-local pc via mapped com port. (if you are unfamiliar with the device I can go into more detail about this)

The NPort device is running in REAL COM MODE, however I notice there are a few other operating modes...
[image]
which got me to thinking that maybe we can have the device communicate with javascript in the clients web browser (websockets). However I am not that knowledgeable to be able to set such a system up - or where I would even start.

Does anyone have experience with this specific device, and how I would go about having it communicate over http?